# Opencv3.2 build on vs2017 error when compile opencv_world with contribute_world

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2015, cmake

*`I selected BUILD_opencv_contrib_world and BUILD_opencv_wolrd flag as True

i configured and generated project but building project give me errors
`*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQyUx.png)

Comment: i got error in intrin.hpp file. i am not sure what is error. anyway error is in opencv_world project. i want get opencv_world with opencv_contribe_world. Please help me

Comment: HI did you solve the problem, I also have the same problem with opencv 3.2

Answer (score 1):

Just configure and generate project without opencv_world. Then build it with VS, go to the official page of opencv, download windows-package, unpack it and copy opencv_world320.lib and opencv_world320.dll to

_YOUR OPENCV_FOLDER_\build\install\x64\vc15\lib for .lib and
_YOUR OPENCV_FOLDER_\build\install\x64\vc15\bin for .dll